# Ruby on rails. rake db:migrate. не находит путь

Tags: ruby-on-rails

rake db:migrate. Пишет что системе не удается найти правильный путь.
ОС:windonws 10.
Ruby 2.3.3
Rails 5.0
Работаю по учебнику Rails 4. Гибкая разработка веб-приложений[так должно быть](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DVL3.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DVL3.png)
но он пишет,что путь не найден.путь указан верно. не может разобрать rake

Comment: добавьте полную ошибку и так же информацию о вашем окружение - ОС, версии и пр.

Comment: что выдает `rake --version`?

Comment: Пишет что системе не удается найти указанный путь.

Comment: переустановите руби и далее по списку

Answer (score 1):

Проблема кроется скорее всего в неправильных путях в самом файле rake.bat.
Файл находится по пути: "Путь к вашей папке с руби\bin\rake.bat"
Нужно открыть данный файл блокнотом и изменить пути к ruby.exe в трех местах этого батника.

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
@"Полный путь к руби\bin\ruby.exe" "Полный путь к руби/bin/rake" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
@"Полный путь к руби\bin\ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
```

и следите чтобы слеши были в нужном направлении. Надеюсь вам поможет, у меня такое прокатило на win10 / Ruby2.3.0 / Rails 4.2.8